# Two sample t-test and normality check

Tags: math, statistics, data-science

I am doing a t-test to see if the average value of two groups A and B are different. 

group A - sample size around 20K 
group B - sample size around 670K 
[t test for A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmDfs.png)

Since P-value is less than alpha I reject the null hypothesis and conclude that the average for group A and group B is different. 
However in order to do a two sample t test one of the requirement is that the sample ( in my case A and B) must be independent and come from a normal distribution. They are independent and since my sample size is large enough with the power of Central Limit Theorem, I am thinking it is good to assume that is from normal distribution.
But I decided to do a normal test to make sure this is true.
A and B come from X, so doing a notmal test on X shows:
[A and B come from X, normal test on X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiEDR.png)
Since p value is less than alpha, we have to reject the null hypothesis ( that the sample comes from a normal distribution) 
Where am I going wrong here? Is the ttest even valid? Is A and B coming from a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A t-test works when the test statistic follows a normal distribution. In this case, the statistic used is the means of the two populations.

Using Central Limit Theorem, if your sample size is large enough, you can assume that the means come from normal distribution. However, it cannot be assumed that the populations themselves are of normal distribution.

T-test doesn't require the assumption that the samples come from normal distribution. It is only requires that the test statistic (in this case, the means) come from normal distribution.

Since the sample size is large enough, hence the means come from normal distribution, t-test can be used on your sample.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer that you may do away with the t test as the sample size is very large which implies the distribution of the sample mean is normal by the central limit theorem (you can define your test statistic as a difference of two samples means coming from normally distributed populations), it is also helpful to calculate the power of the test given the effect size and sample size.

With such large samples, the test can be sensitive enough to detect tiny differences. You might want to ask yourself whether a 0.001 difference in the means would matter in the context of your problem. Because if it doesn't, the test may mislead you in to thinking that the mean of one sample is significantly less or greater than the other sample in a practical sense when it is likely that the effect detected by the test, though statistically significant, may be practically insignificant.